Number of initial segments in a certain poset
For $[n] = \{1,\dotsc,n\}$, the set $\binom{[n]}{k}$ of $k$-element subsets of $[n]$ has a partial order $\leq_p$ induced by the total order on $[n]$. An element $S$ of the set $H(n, k, l) := \binom{\binom{[n]}{k}}{l}$ of $k$-uniform hypergraphs with $l$ edges and $n$ vertices is called shifted if it is an initial segment of this partial order $\leq_p$.
How does $\lvert\{S \in H(n, k, l) \mid \text{$S$ is shifted} \}\rvert$ depend on $n, k, l$?
